# ScreenShot in AndroidDriver selenium

Tags: selenium, appium

I am using appium with selenium for Testing.I am testing my app in GenyMotion virtual device .I want to take screenShot of my login page but i am facing some issue.Please help me out.

Here is my appium server console snap:-

[image]

And here is my app Test configuration code:-

```
public static AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    public static DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @BeforeTest
    public void startAppium() throws MalformedURLException,
            InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("setUP() :: driver.AndroidDriver() executed");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");

        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus");
        cap.setCapability("nativeWebScreenshot", "true");

        cap.setCapability("locationServicesAuthorized", true);// this method
                                                                // check once..
        try {

            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
WebElement loginElement = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='loginButton']"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys(
                    "maddy@ymail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(
                    "Test_36");
            CaptureScreenShot.getSnap(driver);

            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", loginElement);
```

And here is my Snap Class:-

```
public class CaptureScreenShot {

          public static void getSnap(AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver){

              System.out.println("Taking Snaps");
                 File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                 System.out.println("srcFile" + scrFile);
                 try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./snapshots"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

          }


}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting on your Java console